# How to center ul

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a `ul` horizontally centered within the space but no matter what I try it remains left aligned.

```
<nav>
    <div id="home">
    <ul id="topnav">
        <li class="home"><a href="#">home</a></li>
        <li class="products"><a href="#">products</a></li>
        <li class="support"><a href="#">support</a></li>
        <li class="wtb"><a href="#">where to buy</a></li>
        <li class="webstore"><a href="#" target="_blank">web store</a></li>
        <li class="contact"><a href="#">contact us</a></li>
        <li class="facebook"><a href="#" target="_blank"
            title="Hauppauge Computer Works">facebook</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:
[CSS file here](http://www.hauppauge.com/css/nav-sprite-styles2.css)

Comment: Your navigation is not a fixed width (it is 100%), to center something with margin: 0 auto it's container has to have a fixed width

Comment: CSS depends on HTML mark-up, which we don't have. Plus, when posting code, remember: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Please reduce the test-case to a bare minimum that reproduces your problem and then post *that* code (here). And a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) goes a long way to getting good help.

Comment: Thanks! the fixed width fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ul#topnav {
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    position: relative;
    left: auto;
        width: 123px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! the fixed width fixed it.